# Share iPhone for development purpose

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I am new to iPhone development, so hope not asking dump question.
I finished my Xamarin app development, works fine on Android, released. Now finished the iPhone version of it, runs fine on iOS Simulator (without some features, those are not available on Simulator, like email/iap). Now I want to test on a real device, but I don't have iPhone.
However, I got one for about 2 weeks from a friend, who will also develop for it, but will start a bit later, so he does not need it now.

I read through several tutorial, and found that I have to "Add to Member center" the phone, so basically "register" this phone under my apple dev account, when using with proper provisioning profile/certificates.
This is fine, but when I finished testing in let's say **10 days**, and give the phone back to the owner:

1. can he also register this phone to **develop** on this on his account?
2. is it possible to "unregister" myself from this phone (then I won't have any in apple dev center), but keep my App in the Store? Isn't 10 days (too short time) an issue?
3. any other issues with this approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your question i think you are familiar with Apple developer portal & managing Certificates & provisioning profiles. So, i am going to answer your listed points:

1. Yes, a device can be register with different developer account for testing, no issue in it.
2. Yes, you can disable the device from Apple developer portal this will no impact on you App on App Store, because App on store with Distribution Certificate & Provisioning Profile, not with developer Certificate & Provisioning Profile.
3. No issue with this approach, but keep in mind disabling the device will invalidate all associated provisioning profiles, then You can remove the device from your account at the start of your new membership year.

Comment: Thanks Rocky, so according to your answer 1), even no need to remove this device from my Apple dev portal, as others can work with the phone also. Nice. I will wait some, maybe somebody will object, argue some points. After, will accept your answer.